# How can I horizontally center a gallery of variously sized elements without wasting space using pure CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, css-float, display

`text-align:center` on all elements horizontally centers each row

`float:left` on all elements fills vertical space within each row, but rows are no longer centered

Is there a way to get both of these properties at once?

```css
*{
  text-align:center
}
label,input,:checked~*{
  float:left
}
table{
  display:inline-table;
  border:solid transparent;
  border-collapse:collapse
}
td{
  width:1em;
  height:1em;
  line-height:0;
  font-size:xxx-large;
  background-color:silver
}
tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(odd){
  background-color:gray
}
```

```html
<label for=f>float</label><input type=checkbox id=f><table>
  <tr><td>♜<td>♞<td>♝<td>♛<td>♚<td>♝<td>♞<td>♜
  <tr><td>♟<td>♟<td>♟<td>♟<td>♟<td>♟<td>♟<td>♟
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td>♙<td>♙<td>♙<td>♙<td>♙<td>♙<td>♙<td>♙
  <tr><td>♖<td>♘<td>♗<td>♕<td>♔<td>♗<td>♘<td>♖
</table><table><tr><td><td><tr><td><td>
</table><table><tr><td><td><tr><td><td>
</table><table><tr><td><td><tr><td><td>
</table><table><tr><td><td><tr><td><td>
</table><table><tr><td><td><tr><td><td>
</table><table><tr><td><td><tr><td><td>
</table><table><tr><td><td><tr><td><td>
</table><table><tr><td><td><tr><td><td></table>
```

Comment: Why there are so many unclosed tr table td tage?

Comment: @Leothelion closing tags for <tr> and <td> are optional in HTML5. The <table> tags are closed in seemingly odd places because whitespace is significant in HTML and placing each table on its own line would add gaps to the demo which distract from the problem I'm hoping to solve

Comment: i did not get your point which you want to achieve? can you please edit your question so i will get exactly what you want to achieve and i am sure i will be useful. just add little bit more details. Thank you